# Using grep recursively

Tags: search, full-text-search, grep, cygwin

grep has the ability to search recursively using the `-r` option. However, I was wondering if grep has the ability to search for a query string recursively for a specified number of subfolder levels. For instance, I have a folder `root` which has folders `parent1, parent2, ..., parentN`. Each parent folder has normal text files and folders called `child1, child2, ..., childM`. I'd like to run grep from the root level and search in the files inside the parents without looking in the child folders. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: you want to do something like: find /path/to/find -name "nameofthefile"  or want to cat each file to check for a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try these out:

**grep**:

```
 --exclude=GLOB
              Skip files whose base name matches GLOB  (using
              wildcard  matching).   A file-name  glob  can  use *,
              ?, and [...]  as wildcards, and \ to quote a wildcard
              or backslash character literally.

       --exclude-from=FILE
              Skip files whose base name matches any of the file-name
              globs  read  from FILE (using wildcard matching as
              described under --exclude).

       --exclude-dir=DIR
              Exclude directories matching the pattern DIR from
              recursive searches.
```

or use this `find | xargs grep`

with find, you could define the level

**EDIT**

pipe output of one command to another is very common in linux/unix world. I bet you do it everyday.

```
echo "abc"|sed 's/a/x/'
find . -name "*.pyc" |xargs rm
awk 'blahblah' file | sort |head -n2 
tree|grep 'foo'
mvn compile|ack 'error'
...
```

Note that not all examples above are efficient. They are just examples.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Could you explain what the | signifies in your example. I know it can be used to pipe output to a dest, but I don't understand how it makes sense to pipe the output to a different command. In any event, I'm trying your solution and will accept your answer soon.

Answer (score 19):

As [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent) [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15167957/220155), you can't do this with a straight `grep`; it simply isn't powerful enough.  The trick is to use `find` to work out which files to search, and pass the file list that `find` produces to `grep`.

If you run `man find`, you'll get a man page of the *many* options that `find` takes.  The one we're interested in here is `-maxdepth`.

Let's build up the command we need. Run the commands at each stage to see what it looks like:

- `find .` will list all the files and folders that exist in the current folder (`.`) or any descendant folder.
- `find . -maxdepth 1` will list all the files and folders in the current folder. `find . -maxdepth 2` will likewise list for all files and folders in the current folder and any immediate subfolders. And so forth…
- Note that we're getting folders listed too; we don't want this, as `grep` can't search a folder itself, only the files in the folder.  Add `-type f` to only get files listed: `find . -maxdepth 2 -type f`.

Now we know the files we want to search, we need to get `grep` to search those files. The standard way to do this is using `xargs`:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f | xargs grep <text-to-search-for>
```

The `|` takes "standard output", aka "stdout", from `find` (ie what you normally see on screen) and pipes it into `xarg`'s "standard input", aka "stdin", ie what would normally happen if you were typing into a running program.

`xargs` is a cunning little program that runs whatever you tell it to (here, `grep <text-to-search-for>`), after adding all the arguments it received on stdin. The result is that `grep` will search every file that `find` finds.

This doesn't work if some of your file names have spaces in them, though, because `xargs` thinks the space is separating two different file names, rather than a part of one file name. There are a bunch of ways to handle this (the ideal is to just not use spaces in file names), and the common one is to use one of the fancier features of `find`.

If you add an `-exec` argument to `find`, it will execute everything you specify up to a `;` or `+`. If you add a `{}` (that's the literal characters `{` and `}`), it will replace that with a list of all the files. Since `find` is doing that, it knows that spaces in the filename are supposed to be in the filename.

Therefore the best way to do what you're trying to is thus:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 2 -exec grep <text-to-search-for> {} +
```

(The difference between ending with `+` and `;` makes no difference here. If you're interested it's in `man find`, but the short version is that `+` is faster but means you can only have one `{}` in the command.)